# create ndarray::Array2 from specific function

Tags: rust

How do you create ndarray Array2 of a specific shape from a specific function? For example, how do you create a 12x12 multiplication table?

Comment: How did you create an ndarray::Array2 previously? What is different this time that makes it more difficult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`from_shape_fn`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.from_shape_fn), which serendipitously has a multiplication table as its example.